# Pulling information from the Page Source

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Ok so I have been have alot of trouble with the
Web browser control on a few applications I am working on.
All of them share the same issue.  I want to have the application navigate s webpage a read the write the text in the page source to a variable.  I also need to be able to save the files afterwards.

Some Source code:

```
Public Class Form4
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyFolderBrowser As New System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    MyFolderBrowser.Description = "Select the Folder"
    MyFolderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = False
    Dim dlgResult As DialogResult = MyFolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
    If dlgResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = MyFolderBrowser.SelectedPath
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have to select a directory!")
    Else
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.realmofthemadgod.com/version.txt")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Dim PageSource As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.realmofthemadgod.com/AssembleeGameClient" & PageSource & ".swf")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

The first thing I am having an issue with is that it never waits for the webpage to load before pulling the Document text.  I have tried many different ways to from different solutions people have posted to get around this. Oddly it always seems to work if I do it a second time.

And I want to save the final resulting webpage as an swf to the selected directory if Button2 is clicked.

Thanks for any help I have been looking for this everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the dark art of web scraping. First off, I would recommend using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instead of WebBrowser as it has discrete methods for downloading data from web sites. It looks like your version.txt only contains the data you want (and no extraneous html) so we can download it directly. If you needed to parse html I would use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Untested code to get you started:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have to select a directory!")
    Else
        Using wc as New WebClient()
          Dim version = wc.DownloadString("www.realmofthemadgod.com/version.txt")
          Dim swf = "http://www.realmofthemadgod.com/AssembleeGameClient" + version + ".swf"
          wc.DownloadFile(swf,"c:\temp\myswf.swf")
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I will check this out as soon as I get home.  I will also take a look at the pack you mentioned as I will need to parse an html array in a rleated application.  Will the WebClient work in the background, or cause a save as dialog to come to the front?

Comment: It works in the background. There is also an async version if you don't want to block the ui during the request.